# Change scroll speed for specific section and/or button click (SCROLLIFY)

Tags: jquery, jquery-scrollify

Two Questions

1. As the title says, is it possible, with scrollify, to set a different scrollspeed for different sections?
2. I also have a "scrollify.next" button where I tried changing the scrollspeed, but I realized I'm no jquery/js expert. I managed to overwrite the scrollspeed settings on the button event, but how do I properly return the scrollspeed settings after the click event have finished? As it is now, all scrolling after clicking the button will follow the new setting.

I realise I need to re-learn jquery once again, heh!

```
$(".next-btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.scrollify.setOptions({
        scrollSpeed: 2500,
    });
    $.scrollify.next();
});
```

Documentation for scrollify
https://github.com/lukehaas/Scrollify

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code seems fine, can you provide more information about your html?

Comment: Yes, as I said, that code works.But it permanently changes the scrollspeed setting for all the sections after I click the button. I only one that button event to have that specific scrollspeed, after the screen have moved I want the scrollspeed to return to 800.

Comment: Then you can define a global variable for ``scrollSpeed``, like ``scrollSpeed: x``.If the current windows screen == next screen you want, set x = 800...

Comment: Sorry, but that's Chinese for me :/
Are we still talking about Scrollify?

Comment: I am talking about js.. you can define a variable for scrollSpeed, like ``scrollSpeed: x``.When you click next button, assign x to a new value

Comment: That's basically what I've done. I also tried changing it with variables. I have no clue. Basically, when the click event is finished, how do I set the variable back to whatever I want it to be?

Comment: i think you need some method from scrollify (http://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/#methods-continued), like ``$.scrollify.destroy()`` and ``$.scrollify.current()``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the 'after' callback. Wherever Scrollify scrolls to a section it fires the after callback so you can define a new scroll speed within that for any section you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm trying to understand how to use "after:function(){}". The documentation is very vague, and as i'm no JS/jquery dev(only basic knowledge), I have a hard time understanding how to apply the settings inside that callback. I.E; How to target certain sections, change the speed and how to utilise it. Whenever I put anything inside the after callback, the script stops working, so I guess I do something wrong. Here's what I've created.
http://pastebin.com/gAfQRs9H

Comment: Try looking at the source of some of Scrollify's example page like: http://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/examples/apple it makes use of the after callback to control animations within each section

Comment: Thanks Luke Haas. I'll look at how you've done and learn from that. You're awesome :)